# Replacing the day number for each value in a data frame column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, replace, timestamp

I'm trying to replace the day number values within a datetime column using the values from another column.

This is my dataframe:

```
    ID   Code   Day_to_replace  Base_date
0   123  403        28          22/02/2013
1   456  402        21          22/03/2011
2   789  401        14          01/05/2017
```

and this is what I want to end up with:

```
    ID   Code   Day_to_replace  Base_date    New_Date
0   123  403    28              22/02/2013   28/02/2013
1   456  402    21              22/03/2011   21/03/2011
2   789  401    14              01/05/2017   14/05/2017
```

I can do this using a static value but can't work out how to use a value from another column to apply to each record.

```
newdf['New_Date'] = newdf['Base_Date'].apply(lambda x: x.replace(day=1))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First convert values to datetimes:

```
df['Base_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Base_date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

Use [`DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) with `axis=1` for loop per rows:

```
df['New_Date'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['Base_date'].replace(day=x['Day_to_replace']), axis=1)
```

Or convert datetimes to month period and back for first day and add days timedeltas with subtracting `1` by [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
df['New_Date'] = (df['Base_date'].dt.to_period('m').dt.to_timestamp() +  
                  pd.to_timedelta(df['Day_to_replace'].sub(1), unit='d'))
```

Or convert values to strings, add days and convert to datetimes:

```
df['New_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Base_date'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-') + 
                                df['Day_to_replace'].astype(str))
```

---

```
print (df)
    ID  Code  Day_to_replace  Base_date   New_Date
0  123   403              28 2013-02-22 2013-02-28
1  456   402              21 2011-03-22 2011-03-21
2  789   401              14 2017-05-01 2017-05-14
```